# Invalid Type ExternalServiceUtils

Tags: class, instance

I am completely new to salesforce . I have installed SoapBox to interact with the SQL server from salesforce. I have installed its API in the sales force environment as shown below figure.

[image]

This class exposes a number of functions as shown in the below figure.

What is the correct way to call methods and create instance in salesforce.

[image]

and I want to call the UnityDBBrowseServiceCall to get the list of modules.

I am creating an instance of the class in Developer console as shown in the below code

```
ExternalServiceUtils utils = new ExternalServiceUtils();
utils.UnityDBBrowseServiceCall();
```

But when I am executing the code I am getting Invali type: ExternalServiceUtils. How should I call this class and its methods. What is wrong here.

Comment: this is static method call like this `ExternalServiceUtils.UnityDBBrowseServiceCall();`

Answer (score 1):

The code appears to have its own namespace `udc` and the method is static so you need to reference that method like this:

```
udc.ExternalServiceUtils.UnityDBBrowseServiceCall();
```

The namespace allows mutltiple classes to have the same name and be distinguished by the namespace. (Locally created class have no namespace.) When people create their managed package, a unique namespace has to be chosen.

The namespace concept extends to other components too including objects and fields though in that case a double underscore `__` is used as the separator not a dot.

Where a method is `static` you don't need a `new` instance and call the method via the class name.

Comment: That was so dumb of Me. I should have checked the signature of method.